# Typescript error TS2339

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I run a small project which has only one class called iterator which is like below:

**Iterator.class.ts**

```
export class Iterator {
  private itr: any;
  private opt: any;
  private keys: any;
  private type: string;

  constructor(iterable, options) {
    this.itr = iterable;
    this.opt = options;
    this.keys = [];

    this.prepare();
  }

  private prepare() {
    this.type = this.itr.constructor.name.toLowerCase().trim();

    if (['array', 'object'].includes(this.type)) {
      this.keys = Object.keys(this.itr);
    }
  }
}
```

I also installed typescript both with -g flag and local in my project. but whenever I try to compile my iterator.class.ts file into js file, I faced below error:
**iterator.class.ts(18,29): error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.**

This is my tsconfig.json file and I installed all requirements I mentioned in this file like :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2016", "dom"],
    "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

I try both global installed of typescript and the local one and each time I gave the error I mentioned!
I also change target to es2016 and es2017 and add "es2016.array.includes" to lib in tsconfig.js but nothing changed in result. I searched in issues on typescript and non of solutions don't worked for me!

**OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

NODE: v8.2.1

npm: v5.3.0

typescript: v2.4.2 and 2.2.2**

Comment: According to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2340 it should work with `es2017` as lib in tsconfig and TypeScript 2.1+.

Comment: yeah...I try this and all other combinations of es6, es7 (in target property), es2016, es2017, es2016.array.includes (in lib property) but no success.

Comment: Are you compiling this from the command line, Visual Studio, or VS Code? Also, do you have any other packages installed that might depend on TypeScript as a dependency--like a task runner lib?

Comment: Compiling with both terminal and Webstorm IDE has the same result. No this is a tiny project which contains a .ts file and tsconfig.json file. You can see the project in: https://github.com/yass-dev/NODEM